# How to find specific elements with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-traversing

I have a table with checkboxes.

```
<tbody id="myTable">
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td class="userName">Bob</td>
    <td><input id="u1" name="user" type="checkbox" value="1"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>6</td>
    <td class="userName">Izya</td>
    <td><input id="u6" name="user" type="checkbox" value="6"></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

How can I find all `userName`s of all checked inputs and put those names into the array?

Comment: Are you using the same `id` multiple times? The id attribute specifies a unique id for an HTML element (the value must be unique within the HTML document). if it is unique, try `document.getElementById("userName").innerHTML`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe use this dirty code:

```
var tr = $('#myTable > tr'), un = $('#myTable .userName'), check = $('#myTable input[type="checkbox"]'), users = [];
for (var i = 0; i < tr.length; i ++) {
    if (check[i].checked) {
        users.push(un[i].innerText);
    }
}
```

And then in array `users`, the users are there.

Comment: Yes! Its work fine. Dirty code is the best solution as usual :)

Comment: :-) welcome, but you need to make sure there is only one `userName` and only one `checkbox` and no extra `tr`.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
var usernames = $('#myTable')
    .find('tr:has(input.user:checked)')
    .find('.userName').map(function(){
        return $(this).text();
    }).get();
```

It will create an array with all usernames, whose relevant check box is checked

Answer (score 0):

```
<tbody id="myTable">
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td class="userName">Bob</td>
    <td><input id="u1" name="user" type="checkbox" value="1"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>6</td>
    <td class="userName">Izya</td>
    <td><input id="u6" name="user" type="checkbox" value="6"></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

You should use class instead of id, because an id should be unique to the page.

Using jQuery:

$('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked').siblings('.userName').text();

Or if you need the name attribute of the input:

$('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked').attr('name');

http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: Ok. And how can I find all names of checked <input>?

Comment: updated to get name attribute from input, if that's what you wanted.

Comment: It didn't help (both solutions).